# Open a filename with specific file pattern that changes

Tags: python, file, glob

I am using this code below to read contents from a  file because I need to copy the contents of a .mnu file into another .fld file.

```
with open(MS577007.mnu') as myfile:
        contents = myfile.read()
print(contents)
```

the .mnu file changes each month so I am writing a script that automates this. How do I use regex to open the contents in the .mnu file? *.mnu wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all file names which ends with (has an extension of) mnu.

```
from glob import glob

# Find all files
files = glob("*.mnu")
# Loop in files as file
for file in files:
    # Open each file and print content
    with open(file, "r") as myfile:
        contents = myfile.read()
        print(contents)
```